# Trying to understand what this ring notation means

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I saw $(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z - \{0\}, \cdot)$. What does the $-\{0\}$ do?

Comment: consider the cayley table for this with the multiplication modulo 3

Comment: It means take the complement of the set $\{0\}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. the nonzero elements of the ring

Comment: It is an abuse of notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the group obtained from

- the field $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (the integers modulo 3),
- without the additive identity, $0$,
- under the operation of multiplication.

The result has two elements $1 \pmod{3}$ and $2 \pmod{3}$, with the usual multiplication modulo $3$, forming a group, the group of units modulo $3$.

If we leave the additive identity in, we do not get a group, because $0$ has no multiplicative inverse.  (Units are the elements that have multiplicative inverses.)  We get a semigroup, but groups are cool (much like (unrelated) [fezzes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obnblNruPiU) and [bowties](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPGTizdGwSc)).  More generally, we would want to exclude all non-invertible elements.  If we were starting with $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$, we would exclude $0$, $2$, $4$, $5$, $6$, and $8$ modulo $10$, so that the remaining elements can form a group, the group of units modulo $10$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I want to make sure I understand something about rings: So whenever we see $\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z$ it is simply the set of numbers $\{0,1,2,...N-1\}$?

Comment: Not quite, you have written a complete set of *representatives* of the [congruence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_class#Congruence_classes) in $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$.  The class containing $0$ is the set $\{0, \pm N, \pm 2N, \pm 3N, \dots \}$.  You could use any other member of this set as a representative in place of $0$.  This small difference allows us to mean $\overline{N-1} + \overline{2} = \overline{N+1} = \overline{1}$ when we write "$N-1 + 2 \cong N+1 \cong 1 \pmod{N}$ in [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) modulo $N$.

Answer (score 0):

That is the set difference operator. Here, $\mathbb{Z}_{3} - \{0\} = \{ 1, 2\}$. So the multiplicative group for $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ contains the non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$.